# Angular schema form is changing the sf-form variable

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-schema-form

I am creating a flexible schema app using Angular schema form.
When I'm displaying the schema to the user I realized that the framework is altering the sf-form variable.

Please see my jsfiddle her [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0wL78te/2/)

I start with a simple json object:

```
[{
  "key": "name",
  "type": "textarea",
}];
```

After displaying it to the user it the framework has changed the object to this:

```
[
  {
    "key": [
      "name"
    ],
    "type": "textarea",
    "title": "name",
    "description": "Enter name",
    "schema": {
      "title": "name",
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Enter name"
    },
    "ngModelOptions": {
      "updateOnDefault": true
    }
  }
]
```

I need to store the form object to the database, but I do not want to store all the unnecessary part. Please help me out here.